# iOS Mobile Safari portrait layout too zoomed

Tags: iphone, css, ios, ipad, mobile-safari

I would like to have my website look perfect using mobile safari on both the ipad and iphone.  Currently everything looks great in landscape on some pages, but if you change the device to portrait, the whole site gets zoomed in.  I am using mobile specific styles, but how can I fix this problem?

Page that doesn't work: [www.zedsaid.com/apps](http://www.zedsaid.com/apps)

Page that DOES work: [www.zedsaid.com/blog](http://www.zedsaid.com/blog)

CSS:

```
/* iPhone */
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 481px) {
#header {
  width:860px!important;
}
}

/* iPad */
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 768px) {
#header {
  width:860px!important;
}
}
```

I am just not sure why some of my pages scale correctly (blog) but other pages (apps, contact) do not!

Comment: Have you tried playing with the `initial-scale` parameter in your viewport tag?

Comment: did u ever find a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
body * {
-webkit-text-size-adjust: none !important;
}
```

or:

```
/* iPhone */
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 481px) {
#header {
  width: 860px;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
}
}

/* iPad */
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 768px) {
#header {
  width: 860px;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
}
}
```

Comment: Tried it and it doesn't seem to help.